# How to retrieve users associated with multiple roles like ["role1","role2"...]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, roles

I have users and roles relationship as belongsToMany.
I now want to get all users have multiple roles by names.

I have tried as,

```php
 $role_ids = [1,2];
 $users = User::whereHas('roles' , function ($query) use($role_ids) {
            $query->whereIn('roles.id', $role_ids);
        })->get();
```

But this approach gives me users who are associated with both or either one roles which is not i am expecting

Comment: is user belongs to many roles or, role belongs to many users?

Comment: vice-a-versa. Many users belongs to many roles and many roles belongs to many users.

Comment: so please update your question as 'I have users and roles relationship as many-to-many'

Comment: I think both signifies the same in laravel context belongsToMany is nothing but many-to-many

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add multiple `whereHas` for that:

```php
$role_ids = [1,2];
$users = User::with('roles');
foreach($role_ids as $role){
    $users->whereHas('roles', function($q) use ($role){
        $q->where('roles.id', $role);
    });
}
$users = $users->get();
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks for the solution.